# helm bitnami/redis does not provide peristent volume

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3

When I installed with "helm install redis bitnami/redis" then persistent volume claims and persistent volumes were created too. However now, I am trying to run same command but persistent volumes does not seem on Kubernetes. Therefore pod is not running.

Comment: please provide more details

Answer (score 2):

**1. Run `kubectl get pvc`**

- you should see the expected PVCs listed, but in Pending state.
- If you don't see that, this means you are in another namespace

**2. Run `kubectl describe pvc` to investigate why PVCs are pending.**

- sometimes, the dynamic storage provisioner is down, so you need to make it up

### Update

@Onur provided what does "describe pvc" command print :

```
failed to provision volume with StorageClass "do-block-storage":
 rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = volume limit (10) has been reached. 
Current number of volumes: 10. Please contact support."
```

This means that :

- your default storage class (`kubectl get sc`) is named `do-block-storage`.
- that your admin set quota of number of volumes that can used ( which is 10)

Check with your admin to increase the quota of volumes to be used.

Alternatively, try to delete TOTALLY the 1st installation of redis if you don't needed (`kubectl delete pvc ...`) , this will free some PVCs, so you can provision them again.

Comment: Thank you for help. I got this error : "failed to provision volume with StorageClass "do-block-storage": rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = volume limit (10) has been reached. Current number of volumes: 10. Please contact support."

Comment: I updated the answer! i hope it help

Comment: but there is just one pvc, I remove all, but I get the same error again

Comment: Run `kubectl get pvc -A` to check all PVCs in all namespaces.. another thing, check also PV , may be PV is still there `kubectl get pv`

Comment: ı remove volumes from my cloud provider and error has changed. Give me "no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set"  error but helm should create persistent volume too.

Comment: make sure what you have as storage classes `kubectl get sc`, select one of them and use it as per [values scheme of bitnami/redis](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/redis/values.yaml#L19) . i.e. `helm install redis bitnami/redis --set global. storageClass=YOURCLASS`

Comment: I did but pvc stills give this error " no volume plugin matched name: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner"